# LINQ - limit size by group

Tags: c#, linq

In the below code, I am attempting to return the last five elements within each group as a single list, as shown in the below picture.  The below code fails to achieve this, instead the it returns the original dataset (ranged 0-19) as a List.

How can the below code be changed to return the List pictured below?

```
void Main()
{ 
 var dataSet = Enumerable.Range(0, 20);
 var elementsInEachGroup = 5;

 var answer = dataSet.GroupBy(e =>
     new
     {
       oddEven = e % 2,
       e
     })
   .SelectMany(group => group.Skip(Math.Max(0, group.Count() - elementsInEachGroup)))
   .ToList();   

 answer.Dump();
}
```

[image: answer]

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Also, what is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `GroupBy` expression includes the element itself, so each group will contain only a single item. Remove `e` from the `GroupBy` expression, and it will give you the result in the picture.

```
.GroupBy(e =>
    new
    {
        oddEven = e % 2
    })
```

Or simpler

```
.GroupBy(e => e % 2)
```